# How to write this answer in Swift? popToRoot on one tab when the user is in a different tab?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How would this code written in Objective C by XJones, be written in Swift?

Original question: [How to popToRoot on one tab when the user is in a different tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142799/how-to-poptoroot-on-one-tab-when-the-user-is-in-a-different-tab)

Sorry for making  a new question, I could not comment on the original because I don't have enough reputation points.

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UINavigationController *navController = [appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexOfNavController];
[navController popToRootViewController:NO];  // animation not needed but could be YES
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by just loading the viewDidLoad whenever I changed to a New Tab.

```
self.viewDidLoad()
```